# How would be the best way to map all colors onto a square?

Tags: colors

Hex colors are represented as 24 bit integers. All (24 bit) colors can be represented in a cube of dimensions 256*256*256. However 256^3 is also a square, specifically 4096^2, so is it possible to map all colors with all three channels onto a square, but make it look decent? I tried the following method (not exactly just for representation) in shadertoy, where i and j are the x,y coordinates of pixels on a 4096x4096 square:

```c
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec2 colorCoords = uv*4095.0;
    float colorIndex = colorCoords.x + colorCoords.y*4096.0;
    float red = mod(floor(colorIndex / 65536.0), 256.0) / 255.0;
    float green = mod(floor(colorIndex / 256.0), 256.0) / 255.0;
    float blue = mod(colorIndex, 256.0) / 255.0;
    fragColor = vec4(red, green, blue, 1);
    
}
```

[image]
Do you think this is wrong, or could look better, and more human readable?